# Create a tmp directory for each user

Tags: ssh, login

I stumbled upon this page : http://www.wlug.org.nz/PerUserTempDirs

Suggesting to create/replace a few scripts; the latest step is more confusing :

> Now once you have that in place,
>   invoke the following script instead of
>   login(1):

```
 #!/bin/sh
 mkdir -m 700 /tmp-safe/user/"$1" /tmp/"$1"
 chown "$1":  /tmp-safe/user/"$1" /tmp/"$1"
 mount --bind /tmp-safe/user/"$1" /tmp/"$1" || exit 1
 exec /bin/login "$@"
```

Since users login with ssh, i 'think' that /bin/login is never executed. What script should I modify to be able to re-mount /tmp for the user ?

Comment: Uhhh.... that may not work as you expect. mount --bind is systemwide, it does not result in each user having their own view of /tmp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with pam_mktemp is, there are lots of software with hardcoded `/tmp`, and they do not honor the TMPDIR variable.

"Namespaces" feature in recent kernels can be used for this, as explained in [a blog post by a Gentoo developer](http://blog.flameeyes.eu/2008/03/07/private-temporary-directories).

Answer (score 3):

A better approach is to use [pam_mktemp](http://www.openwall.com/pam/). This will create a per-user directory under /tmp when a user logs in via any pam service and updates TMP and TMPDIR to use that. This does rely on programs being written to not assume /tmp.